# Vertical triangle css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, styles

I need to create full width, transparent triangle with border and some elements inside  via CSS. Does somebody know how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: @vee, thanks. I'll try to play with it, but I'm not sure that it will help. I don't know how to put border around white bg, because it generates triangles using border.

Comment: Maybe use [this link](https://editor.method.ac/) to generate triangle as svg file and use as background image.

Comment: @vee, yeah, thanks. I came up to this too, but using figma. Thanks for replying. You can write it as an answer. I think it is the one of best way to make this triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create triangle as vector (svg) [here](https://editor.method.ac/).
You can convert from svg file to base64 [here](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image/svg).

```css
body {
    background-color: #444;
}

#triangle {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iODAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjgwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KIDxnPgogIDx0aXRsZT5MYXllciAxPC90aXRsZT4KICA8cGF0aCBpZD0ic3ZnXzEiIGQ9Im0yLjk5LDc5Ni44MzM4MmwzOTYuOTk5OTgsLTc5My43NTA3bDM5Ni45OTk5OCw3OTMuNzUwN2wtNzkzLjk5OTk3LDB6IiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmZmZmIi8+CiA8L2c+Cgo8L3N2Zz4=");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
#circle {
    background-color: #7220fd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 90px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 20%);
    width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle">
    <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[See it on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64cfg97b/).

You did not provide any code or background image to use, I have to generate new for testing and the result may not exactly to your screenshot. However you can change the triangle vector using the link above.

To customize circle position, change the argument of [`translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()). The first is horizontal position, second is vertical position.